# Prevent generating new timestamp for all eclipse plugins

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-mars

I have an eclipse rcp product, which has one feature, which has many plugins.  All of my plugins have 1.0.0.qualifier type syntax in the version numbers.  When I change a plugin, the qualifier gets exported as a timestamp.  However, it changes all qualifiers to the current timestamp, which has the undesirable effect of causing the user to download all plugins again.

I've tried to add this in my feature's build.properties (but it didn't help):
generateFeatureVersionSuffix=true

I've looked at:
http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.pde.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fpde_version_qualifiers.htm

I've looked at this as well:
[Accessing the timestamp after PDE build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22961293/accessing-the-timestamp-after-pde-build)

But I can't find anything related to changing the qualifier based on code changes.  I know I can remove the qualifier and manually increment the plugins, but it would involve remembering to do so at every code change by the developer.  Is there a simple solution for this?

Comment: The qualifier is intended to identify builds, not code changes - the first three parts of the version are for that.

Comment: So is there an out of the box solution to change the first three parts automatically on code change?

Comment: I have never seen anything.

Answer (score 1):

Your best solution, assuming that you do builds with Tycho (if not, you probably should) and you use git is to use [Tycho Reproducible Version Qualifiers](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Reproducible_Version_Qualifiers).

Using it will produce the same version number for the same source code, based on git hash.